# Prove existence of a certain point

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

> Let $p(x)$ be an odd degree polynomial in one variable with co-efficients from the set of real numbers.Let $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be  a bounded continuous function.Prove that there exists an $x_0$ such that $p(x_0)=g(x_0)$

**My try:**

Define $h:p-g$ where $p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ where $n=$ odd and $g$ is bounded continuous and hence $|g(x)|\le K$

Without loss of generality we assume that $a_n>0$

Then if we put $N$ large then we have $p(N) \to \infty$.
So $h(x)\to \infty $ as  $ g$ is bounded.

Similarly if we put $N$ very small then $p(N)\to -\infty$.So $h(x)\to -\infty $ as  $ g$ is bounded.

Now $h$ is continuous and changes sign so there exists $p$ such that $h(p)=0\implies p(x_0)=g(x_0)$

Is it right?Please suggest edits if required.

Comment: It's just fine. Maybe replace "$N$ very small" by "$N$ a large negative number".

Comment: use Bolzano Theorem or Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: @EthanBolker large negative number is extremely confusing

Comment: Bolzano Theorem not Bolzano Weierstrass . it's indeed IVT when the certain point is zero.

Comment: @user251257 I agree that it's weird, but I don't think it's confusing. I'm pretty sure I've seen it written that way. "Negative number with large absolute value" would be correct, of course, but (I think) pedantic. As a teacher I'd accept the OP's answer as written.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I still don't get why you suggested something that op already did...

Comment: Thank you very much @EthanBolker

Comment: Thank you very much @user251257

Comment: The terminology "large negative number" is completely standard usage. Also, "small" means "close to zero". Saying that one number is less than another number isn't the same thing as saying that it is smaller. "Large" and "small" refer to magnitude, while "lesser" and "greater" refer simply to order.

Comment: @MPW: probably it is just the english language that confuses me :)

Comment: The thing is, if $f$ is an odd-order polynomial, then the range of $f$ is $\mathbf R$. So $f$ takes on every value of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ that $-m<g(x)<M$ ($g$ is bounded). $p$ is a polynom from an ood degree so if the coeffisient fo $x^{deg(f)}$ is positive $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{p(x)}=\infty \\ \lim_{x \to -\infty}{p(x)}=-\infty $$
So we can find $x_0$ big enough that $p(x_0)>M>g(x_0)$ and $x_1$ small enough that $p(x_1)<-M<g(x_1)$ and use the Mid Value Theorem.
Or if $x^{deg(f)}$ is negative $$\lim_{x\to  \infty}{p(x)}= - \infty \\ \lim_{x \to - \infty}{p(x)}=\infty $$
With similarity: We can find $x_0$ big enough that $p(x_0)<-M<g(x_0)$ and $x_1$ small enough that $p(x_1)>M>g(x_1)$ and use the Mid Value Theorem.
Q.E.D